# Parameters empty (or not supplied to CommandText) when using NLog with ASP.NET Core and SQLite

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog, asp.net-core-2.1, system.data.sqlite

I've set up NLog in an ASP.NET Core MVC application using the examples in the documentation. Logging to a file (target=file) works without any problems.

However, logging to the Sqlite database results in an exception:

> 2018-10-30 20:04:41.4394 Error DatabaseTarget(Name=db): Error when
>   writing to database. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Must
>   add values for the following parameters: @MachineName, @Logged,
>   @Level, @Message, @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
>   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.WriteEventToDatabase(LogEventInfo
>   logEvent)    at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.Write(LogEventInfo
>   logEvent)

Any ideas why the values of these parameters are empty? Or maybe the parameters are not passed at all?

NLog configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="nlog-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${machinename}|${level:upperCase=true}|${logger}|${callsite}|${message} ${exception:tostring}" />

    <target xsi:type="Database"
            name="db"
            dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection, Microsoft.Data.Sqlite"
            connectionString="Data Source=database.db;">

      <commandText>
        INSERT INTO Log (MachineName, Logged, Level, Message, Logger, CallSite, Exception)
        VALUES (@MachineName, @Logged, @Level, @Message, @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception);
      </commandText>

      <parameter name="@MachineName" layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@Logged" layout="${longdate}" />
      <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}" />
      <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@CallSite" layout="${callsite}" />
      <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="db" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Maybe check if command-text-casing, parameter-name-casing and column--name-casing in database is completely identical. Sqlite seems to be case-sensitive.

Comment: @RolfKristensen It doesn't look like a Sqlite issue, but I can confirm that the column names and parameter names match both in writing and casing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to fix the issue using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite I switched to using [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite)) instead, which fixed the issue right away.

Remove the `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` reference and add a reference `System.Data.SQLite` (1.0.109.2 at the time of writing) in your *.csproj* file. Update the `dbProvider` attribute value in *nlog.config* to `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite` and you're set.

*nlog.config snippet:*

```
<target xsi:type="Database"
            name="db"
            dbProvider="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite"
            connectionString="Data Source=database.db;">
   ...
</target>
```